# jQuery pass object in inline onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass `object` to inline `onclick event`. When I try following code I either get `undefined` or `[object object]`.

also how can I bind click event to `h` to avoid inline code.

```
this.get = function(o) {
  console.log(o, o.foo);
}

this.somefunction = function(robj) {
  for (var i = 0, i <= robj.length; i++) {
    var fname = robj[i]['filename']
    h += '<div class="checkbox checkbox-success" onclick="get(\'' + robj + '\')">' +
      '<input id="' + fname + '" type="checkbox" class="styled"> ' +
      '<label for="' + fname + '"><a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="#">' + fname + '</a></label>' +
      '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: declare the get function outside of document.ready

Comment: Is there any other solution without declaring it outside document ready ?

Comment: yes,,,,,you can assign a global scope..and then assign the get function with the global scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems I saw with your code,

1. your loop should be `i < robj.length` and has a syntax error `,` should be `;`
2. `h` was not defined but now not used anymore
3. The array passed into `get()` cannot be accessed by using `o.foo`

Side note: take a look at ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to help clean up some of the quoting action you are currently doing, for example `id="' + fname + '"` can look like `id="${fname}"`

Here is a full working example with the fixes above on how you can add a listener to your div (by creating DOM element) and with the object as a parameter.

```js
this.get = function(o) {
  console.log(o);
  console.log(o.foo);
}

this.somefunction = function(robj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < robj.length; i++) {
    var fname = robj[i]['filename']
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.className = "checkbox checkbox-success";
    myDiv.onclick  = function(){get(robj[i])};
    myDiv.innerHTML =
      '<input id="' + fname + '" type="checkbox" class="styled"> ' +
      '<label for="' + fname + '"><a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="#">' + fname + '</a></label>';
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(myDiv);
  }
}
var robj = [{filename: "myFilename", foo: "myFoo"}]
somefunction(robj);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: your onclick method doesn't help much here. it'll always pass `myFoo`. what about `filename`?

Comment: it passes the whole object to the `get()` method, which includes `filename` and `foo` properties.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of dynamically written onclick . simply keep the function outside of doucment.ready

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function changePath(distinct_inputs)
    {
        console.log(distinct_inputs);
    }
    
     
$(document).ready(function(){

     
var distinct_inputs = 0;
    $('.icon1').click( function(){
        distinct_inputs = distinct_inputs + 1 ;
        $('#insert-file').append('<ul class="ul list-inline"><li style="width:90%"><input onchange="changePath('+distinct_inputs+')" type="file" class="base'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-base"><input  type="text" class="fake'+distinct_inputs+' form-control form-input form-style-fake" readonly placeholder="choose your file"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open input-place"></span></li><li class="icon fa fa-minus"></li></ul>');
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="insert-file" ></div>
<button type="button" class="icon1">CLick here</button>

</body>
</html>
```